# XAttribute contains encoded HTML

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML element defined in a document:

```
<modelDef name="EmployeeOutput" description="Current Model Run output.">
    <resultSet name="Values">
        <field name="Net P&amp;L Impact" typeName="Decimal" formatString="C2"/>
    </resultSet>
</modelDef>
```

Notice the name attribute on the field element.  When I retrieve the value it comes back with the ampersand, where I want to keep the encoded value as defined in the xml.  This is the simple code I use to retrieve the value of the attribute

```
field.Attribute("name").Value
```

How can I make sure that I get the &amp code back rather than the actual ampersand symbol?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I am taking the XML that I have been given and putting it into another XML document and can't lose the original formatting of the attribute value.  Eventually you guys are right that I will want to display the actual ampersand, but at this point I do not.

Comment: Then the code that creates the other XML document should handle that. There is nothing to lose here, `&` in an attribute will be again encoded as `&amp;`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, "Net P&L Impact" *is* the value you've encoded in XML, because `&amp;` is the XML code for an ampersand. If the actual encoded *value* should be `"Net P&amp;L Impact"` then you need to change your XML:

```
<modelDef name="EmployeeOutput" description="Current Model Run output.">
    <resultSet name="Values">
        <field name="Net P&amp;amp;L Impact" typeName="Decimal" formatString="C2"/>
    </resultSet>
</modelDef>
```

However, it's rare to encounter real-world entities with `&amp;` in their names. Why do you want it to be encoded that way? Is it because you're outputting it to HTML? If so, use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` on the resulting value as you go to output it in HTML. That's the correct and safe way. Don't expect your XML-parsing code to anticipate the context that the value will be output into.